# how to use Android CardsUI library in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

I am trying to use this library http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/cardsui/. Import, libs folder and external JAR does not work.

[image: this is what is ee]

Comment: You do know that a library "can't run"? You always need a project that uses this library... Have you added the library in the "Android" settings entry on the screenshot you provided? Click on Android, scroll down, add the library project instead of adding the jar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Android library project. It is not an app.

You need to attach the Android library project to your app's project. The process for this [is detailed in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject). Basically, given that you have already imported the library into your Eclipse workspace, you right-click over your app project in the Package Explorer, choose Properties > Android, scroll down to the Libraries section, click the Add button, and choose your imported library.

Comment: thank you,I found this menu... and after choose imported library.. no need to do any other import? then I can use?

Comment: @chanjianyi: I cannot answer that specifically, as I have never used this particular Android library project. If you have further questions about this specific library, you might consider contacting its author.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just import the jar file for this project because it requires additional resources such as images. Therefore it needs to be imported as a library project